# Chromium not able to install the extensions from Chrome Webstore

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome, chromium, extension, chrome-extension

I have Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr version installed in my system(32bit).

And my Chromium version is 50.0.2661.102.

When I try to install any extension from Chrome Webstore (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/extensions?hl=en) it doesn't install, instead it keeps on throwing error as below:

```
There was a problem adding the item to Chrome. Please refresh the page and try again.
Hide details
Image decode failed
```

Also it doesn't show images on the extension areas in Chrome Webstore. Anyone can help me out ?

Comment: It is chromium issue, not Ubuntu issue

Comment: Works fine here but I'm on 64 bit. Maybe related to google- chrome dropping 32 bit? (though see no news saying that..

Comment: Not sure if it's a Chromium bug, because my collegues who have 64bit ubuntu 14.04 have no issues installing extensions, maybe in Ubuntu 32bit systems, chromium connectivity to internet is buggy. Or some bug in Chromium installation or permissions.

Comment: No updates on this yet ?